# How to modify .class during apk building process?

Tags: android, gradle, build, apk, dex

I have a basic idea on how Android apps are built and run. What I want to do is to write a gradle task in order to modify the .class generated by the java compiler or modify the .dex before that apkbuilder builds the apk. I think is quiet similar to what proguard do. But I have no idea on how to break the build process exactly where I want.
Is there any gradle plugin?

Apk repackaging is not a good idea what I need is something that can be integrated during build process.

Comment: You can use annotation processing to modify the compiled class files. See, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25649442/how-do-i-use-custom-java-annotation-processor-in-gradle

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm not sure that this solve my problem. Substantially what I want is to change the name of the native functions used at java level and implemented at native one. The main requirement is avoid to modify the source code (no easy way with script).